# API-Gateway integration with AWS Service / DDB with URL Encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity-template-language

trying to make PhoneTrack (https://gitlab.com/eneiluj/phonetrack-android/-/wikis/userdoc) work with my API-Gateway to receive location data. I have setup my API to work with a post request, and if I curl it with encoding `application/jason`, it works fine. the issue is that the app is using encoding of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I have setup two mapping templates and I have tried a few combinations to make the mapping work, but the x-www-form-urlencoded template just does not seem to do anything, and I think I have not fully understood how to get this right.

here my terraform resource:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "ddb_integration" {
  depends_on              = [aws_api_gateway_method.generic_post]
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.generic_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.generic_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.generic_post.http_method
  passthrough_behavior    = "NEVER"
  content_handling        = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${local.workspace.aws_region}:dynamodb:action/PutItem"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.api_gw_to_ddb.arn
  type                    = "AWS"
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<-EOF
    {
      "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.generic_data.name}",
      "Item": {
        "lon": {
          "N": "$input.json('$.lon')"
        },
        "lat": {
          "N": "$input.json('$.lat')"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "S": "$input.json('$.timestamp')"
        }
      }
    }
    EOF

    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" = <<-EOF
    {
      $util.log("Starting processing input body...")
      #foreach( $token in $input.body.split('&') )
          $util.log("Current token: $token")
          
          #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
          #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
          $util.log("Split token into key and value. KeyValSize: $keyValSize")
          
          #if( $keyValSize >= 1 && !$keyVal[0].isEmpty() )
              #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
              $util.log("Decoded key: $key")
              
              #set($key = $key.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + $key.substring(1))
              $util.log("Processed key with first letter lower-cased: $key")
              
              #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
                  #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
                  $util.log("Decoded value: $val")
                  
                  #if( $key == "lon" || $key == "lat" || $key == "timestamp" )
                      $util.log("$key: $val")
                  #end
                  
              #else
                  #set( $val = '' )
                  $util.log("No value found for key. Setting value to empty.")
              #end
              
              "$key": "$util.escapeJavaScript($val)"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
              
          #else
              $util.log("Error processing token: $token. Either key is missing or empty.")
          #end
      #end
      $util.log("Finished processing input body.")
    }
    EOF
  }
}
```

This works for the `application/json` version. The logging I have tried to setup in the Apache Velocity Template Language, template code does not seem to be logging out to cloudwatch, so i dont really seem to have a way to look into how this works. I have also tried to use the simplest version of this for url encoding as:

```
{
    "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.generic_data.name}",
    "Item": {
      "lon": {
        "N": "$util.urlDecode($input.params('lon'))"
      },
      "lat": {
        "N": "$util.urlDecode($input.params('lat'))"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "S": "$util.urlDecode($input.params('timestamp'))"
      }
    }
  }
```

but this also does not work. Below my execution logs from APIG, the obvious issue being a serialisation exception.

The problem is obviously that the URL encoded object payload is not being converted into something that DDB can understand. So the issue is that the mapping template is not doing its magic. Will this work, or do I need to use a lambda to get this to function?

The Apache VTL does not seem to do anything for URL encoded payloads, however, it does seem to process fine for json encoded payloads. Is there a way to get the logging feature working with VTL?

```
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Extended Request Id: MGm12FcyoAMEsgA=
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Verifying Usage Plan for request: REQUEST_ID_REMOVED. API Key:  API Stage: STAGE_ID_REMOVED/prod
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) API Key  authorized because method 'POST /data' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key  and API Stage STAGE_ID_REMOVED/prod
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Starting execution for request: REQUEST_ID_REMOVED
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /data
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Method request path: {}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Method request query string: {}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Method request headers: {User-Agent=curl/8.3.0, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=REMOVED_IP, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Host=REMOVED, X-Forwarded-Port=443, accept=*/*}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Method request body before transformations: lon=151.0&lat=-33.0&timestamp=1695994041
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Endpoint request URI: https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=PutItem
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=REMOVED, X-Amz-Date=20231001T034528Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=STAGE_ID_REMOVED, Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_STAGE_ID_REMOVED, X-Amz-Security-Token=REMOVED
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Endpoint request body after transformations: lon=151.0&lat=-33.0&timestamp=1695994041
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Sending request to https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=PutItem
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Received response. Status: 400, Integration latency: 6 ms
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Endpoint response headers: {Server=Server, Date=Sun, 01 Oct 2023 03:45:28 GMT, Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.0, Content-Length=60, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=REMOVED, x-amz-crc32=REMOVED}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Endpoint response body before transformations: {"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 400
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 500
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Gateway response body: {"message": "An unexpected error occurred."}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Gateway response headers: {x-amzn-ErrorType=InternalServerErrorException}
(REQUEST_ID_REMOVED) Method completed with status: 500
```

Ive tried many different combinations of the mapping template, with assistance from GPT. Ive tried to log out data as verbosely as possible in the hope that something will jump out, but I cant get past this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 400 exception, which you have not set up a response mapping for so you're not sure of the true cause of the error. My hunch is you are getting a `ResourceNotFoundException`, and I believe your way of parsing the table name in your VTL is not correct. Get the table name and hardcode it into your template and retry. That'll let you identify the cause of the issue which you can then work on fixing.

Also set up an exception template so you know what errors you're getting.

Comment: You are correct that the table name was missing, and I fixed this. There is a char limit preventing me pasting in the latest logs, but the table name is now showing, but the url string vars are not being picked up still. I moved back to the simpler version of the mapping template, and it does not discover the vars in the body.
 "message": "One or more parameter values are not valid. The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. Key: timestamp"

Comment: {
    "TableName": "genericDataTable",
    "Item": {
        "lon": {
            "S": ""
        },
        "lat": {
            "S": ""
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "S": ""
        }
    }
}

Comment: Have you tried without decoding, just passing the input directly?

Comment: great suggestion. on doing this I quickly found that the data object being recieved is key called `datastring` with a value of a bse64 encoded string, which obviously needs to be decoded to be usable. There is no hint that apig is automatically decoding this string in the log, and that the data object remains a base64 string. how frustrating. I cannot seem to make `$util.base64Decode()` do anything. how else could I extract my params?

Comment: after a bit more research, I find that I had set `content_handling="CONVERT_TO_TEXT"`in my terraform, and this converts the payload to base64. I had to turn this off.

Comment: This works for me:
```
#set($decoded = $util.urlDecode($input.body))
#set($params = {})
#foreach($param in $decoded.split("&"))
    #set($keyValue = $param.split("="))
    #set($params[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1])
#end

{
    "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.generic_data.name}",
    "Item": {
        "longitude": {
            "N": "$params.lon"
        },
        "latitude": {
            "N": "$params.lat"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "N": "$params.timestamp"
        }
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need to use the decode function on your data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference

$util.urlDecode() and use it in conjunction with your payload,
$util.urlDecode($input.body).

these commands will get you a list of params with the names in the payload, and then you can reference them with the params.name after.

```
#set($decoded = $util.urlDecode($input.body))
#set($params = {})
#foreach($param in $decoded.split("&"))
    #set($keyValue = $param.split("="))
    #set($params[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1])
#end

{
    "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.generic_data.name}",
    "Item": {
        "longitude": {
            "N": "$params.lon"
        },
        "latitude": {
            "N": "$params.lat"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "S": "$params.timestamp"
        }
    }
},
  "debug": {
        "timestamp": "$params.timestamp",
        "decoded_lon": "$params.lon",
        "decoded_lat": "$params.lat",
        "decoded_body": $util.escapeJavaScript($decoded),
        "request": {
            "parameters": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params())"
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot grab the parameters out of the query string without decoding it first.

My working terraform integration resource:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "ddb_integration" {
  depends_on           = [aws_api_gateway_method.generic_post]
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.generic_api.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.generic_resource.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.generic_post.http_method
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
  # content_handling        = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${local.workspace.aws_region}:dynamodb:action/PutItem"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.api_gw_to_ddb.arn
  type                    = "AWS"

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<-EOF
#set($decoded = $util.urlDecode($input.body))
#set($params = {})
#foreach($param in $decoded.split("&"))
    #set($keyValue = $param.split("="))
    #set($params[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1])
#end

{
    "TableName": "${aws_dynamodb_table.generic_data.name}",
    "Item": {
        "longitude": {
            "N": "$params.lon"
        },
        "latitude": {
            "N": "$params.lat"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "S": "$params.timestamp"
        }
    }
},
  "debug": {
        "timestamp": "$params.timestamp",
        "decoded_lon": "$params.lon",
        "decoded_lat": "$params.lat",
        "decoded_body": $util.escapeJavaScript($decoded),
        "request": {
            "parameters": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params())"
        }
    }
}
EOF
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So after some testing, this did not work for me, I managed to get it working in the testing console of apig, but not via the app. One of the issues I ran into was that the incoming url encoded content type, always defaulted to the json content type, and I could not get it to work properly with its own type, nor could I get the url encoding to work from the app to decode the string, even if I could get it to semi work in the test console.